# How to fix the blank line added to my downloaded files?

Tags: download, migration, php-5.6, apache2.4, blank-line

I'm using an upgraded version of phpwiki. Before, it was running on Centos 6 with Apache 2.2, Php 5.3 and Mysql 5.1. Now it works on Centos 7 with Apache 2.4, Php 5.6 and Mariadb 10.3.

But there is still one issue : when I download a previously uploaded file that is stored on the server, this file is exactly the same, but with a blank line at the beginning.

First, I verified if the file is stored or not with this blank line to understand if the problem was related to either the download or the upload.
There is no space at the beginning so the issue is apparently when I download it.

As well, I observed that the download is managed by providing the direct URL of the file thanks to an  statement :

```
<a href="https://mywebsite.com/wiki/uploads/101/file.txt">file.txt</a>
```

In facts, the filename is stored in the database with a field that describe the path on the server (in the previous example, "file.txt" and "wiki/uploads/101/file.txt")

So I'm wondering if the problem is not in the configuration of Apache or Php.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I tried to use the "file" function in ssh to see if the file is encoded with DOM but it's not the case.

I also tried to see if the downloaded file is still wrong if I manually upload the file at the location in ssh thanks to scp. The problem is the same with the downloaded file.

Does somebody have any other idea that can solve my problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: After a few test, the problem is not only on the wiki part on the site. Everywhere I'm downloading a file from the server, there is a blank line added at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

At the end of a php file, there was a blank line after the "?>" statement.

Removing it solved my problem.

My thought process was removing all blank lines after this statement recursively in my website www folder. After seeing that this solved my problem, I reverted my changes and tried subfolder by subfolder to do the same thing to find easily the concerned file. And I repeated the same process file by file to find the concerned file.